# Avoid duplicate records to be saved - Angular 6 - Mat-Table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

Is there any way to check whether the Mat-Table row or cells dirty with new values?

I'm not able to find a proper way to do dirty check from the official angular material site.

what am trying to achieve is. Save button (in parent component) should be enabled/disabled based on value changes in a table row(in child component). for that, **Assumption**,

```
if(tableCell_isDirty === true) {
// enable save btn
} else {
// disable btn if new row is empty or no changes
}
```

As I don't find 'dirty' property for Mat-Table, I simply did an empty check like

```
if(this.myservice.table[0].custName === '') {
// dont save records
}
```

but am failed in above logic due to some other existing logics.

Simply, I don't want empty records to be saved in Mat-Table while hitting the save button.

Kindly help me to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: I presume if each row was its own form (in its own child component) you could check the form itself.

Comment: @Jacquesジャック i dont use forms. but doing something like this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwbczv?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Comment: "dirty", and other states used on inputs are for forms. I'm not sure what dirty means from the context of a table row if it's not in a form.

Comment: 'Dirty' in the sense, if the current state of the input is changed it becomes dirty or modified or updated. Assume, there is the bunch of input boxes with data onload. and am creating new row which generated with empty columns so by nature the state of the column/row/table cell is empty. if I give input then the state changed with value. correct me if am wrong in explanation

Comment: What I’m saying is that the input can be dirty. The table row cannot be.